# Convert Matplotlib plot to Numpy array faster

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

How can I convert matplotlib plot to numpy array faster

I currently use the agg backend, converting 10 million plots to numpy arrays and store those in a list.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from Game import Draw

images = []
fig = plt.figure(num=1)

for i in range(10000000):
    Draw(i)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
    data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
images.append(data)
```

(The `Draw` function contain some plt.plot functions)
Currently, it's on 5 fps, my goal is to get around 200 fps. any ideas?

Comment: If there is one `plt.plot` command in `Draw`, the first image will contain one line, but the 10 millionth image will contain 10 million lines. If assuming infinite memory, drawing the last image will hence (roughly) be 10 million times slower than drawing the first image and therefore the notion of *fps* does not make much sense here. Also drawing 10 million lines will sure be much faster using a `LineCollection`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. After about 100K steps everything is much slower. The Draw function has few ```plt.plot```, plotting a game, frame by frame (each frame is different than the other). Two question - first: why the memory problem you described happened? and secondly, how should I avoid it? (should I add ```plt.clf()```?)